# nginx and cookie redirect

Tags: redirect, cookies, nginx, config

I need some nginx PRO to help me with this. I have one secret page at my site which I need to protect from scan bots and bruteforcers (actually this is login page). I need to redirect anybody to 404 page if one trying to access this page without special cookie. And I need this page to work very good if the cookie set on. Lets look to my config:

```
server {
        listen  80;
        server_name  example.com;
        root   /var/www/example.com/;
        index  index.php;
        client_max_body_size 64M;

        location ~* /(secret\-page\.php/).*$ {
#                if ($cookie_secretauth != "123123") {
                        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /not-found;
#                }
        }

        location / {
                if (!-e $request_filename) {
                    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php last;
                }
        }

        location ~* ^/(images|data|t)/.+.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
                access_log        off;
                expires max;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index  index.php;
                #.....more things
        }
}
```

Look at the commented lines. When that lines are commented out, the redirect works well. As soon as I remove comments, it become downloading my PHP code instead of redirecting me! What I am doing wrong? My head is broken.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have to add the PHP handler inside the `secret-page.php` location, so that it will pass to PHP.

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name  example.com;
    root   /var/www/example.com/;
    index  index.php;
    client_max_body_size 64M;

    location ~* /(secret\-page\.php/).*$ {
            if ($cookie_secretauth != "123123") {
                    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /not-found;
            }
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            #.....more things
    }

    location / {
            if (!-e $request_filename) {
                rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php last;
            }
    }

    location ~* ^/(images|data|t)/.+.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
            access_log        off;
            expires max;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            #.....more things
    }
}
```

Comment: There is relatively huge block.. why I need to repeat this block? Look, there is a block with rewrite to index.php and location ~ \.php executes after it normally.